# Отправить данные из бота в google sheets

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, google-spreadsheet

Очень нужна помощь.

Есть многофункциональный бот на питоне, telebot.

Нужно добавить функцию заявки.

Пользователь, используя команду или написав «Заявка» вызывает эту функцию.

Функция в том, что бот по порядку запрашивает данные у пользователя и после всех введенных даных отправляет эти данные в гугл таблицу.

В общем то и все, вроде должно быть просто, но не могу найти в интернете именно то , что мне нужно.

Очень надеюсь , что кто-то сможет мне помочь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

[**Aiogram**](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py) смотрите, там есть состояния, которые сформируют список.
Потом отправите его, вот пример, как авторизовать лк [Google для Python](http://datalytics.ru/all/rabotaem-s-api-google-drive-s-pomoschyu-python/)
док по [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet)